# want to skip all line comments except two in antlr4 grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I want to extend the [IDL.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/idl/IDL.g4) grammar a bit so that I can distinguish the following two comments `//@top-level false` and `//@top-level true`, all other comments I just want to skip like before.

I have tried to add `top_level`, `TOP_LEVEL_TRUE`and `TOP_LEVEL_FALSE`like this, because I thought antr4 gave precedence to lexical rules comming first.

```
top_level
  : TOP_LEVEL_TRUE
  | TOP_LEVEL_FALSE
  ;

TOP_LEVEL_TRUE
  : '//@top-level true'
  ;

TOP_LEVEL_FALSE
  : '//@top-level false'
  ;

LINE_COMMENT
  : '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\' -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

But the listener `enterTop_level(...)` is never called, 
all comments seems to be eaten by LINE_COMMENT. How shall I organize the lexer and parser rules?

And one more question, I also want to be notified when end of input-file is reached. How do I do that? I have tried a `finalize()` function i the listener class, but never get called.

**Updated with a complete example:**

I use this grammar file : [IDL.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/idl/IDL.g4) as I said above. Then I update it by putting the parser rule `top_level` just below the `event_header` rule. The Lexer rules is put just above the ID rule.

Here is my Listener.java file

```
class Listener extends IDLBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterTop_level(IDLParser.Top_levelContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("Found top-level");
    }
}
```

and here is a main program: IDLCheck.java

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class IDLCheck {
    public void process(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("sample.idl");
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
        IDLLexer lexer = new IDLLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        IDLParser parser = new IDLParser(tokens);
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
        RuleContext tree = parser.specification();
        Listener listener = new Listener();
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        walker.walk(listener, tree);    
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new IDLCheck().process(args);
  }
}
```

and a input file: sample.idl

```
module CommonTypes {
  struct WChannel {
    int w;
    float d;
  }; //@top-level false
  struct EPlanID {
    int kind;
    short index;
  }; //@top-level TRUE
};
```

I expect to see the output "Found top-level" twice, but I see nothing

Comment: Could you provide a sample input please? I just ran this grammar and did not have any issues. Also, I suggest using `skip` instead of `channel(HIDDEN)` for comments.

Comment: Answer to my last question about how to be notified when eof in an .idl-file. I simply added a eof to the start rule: `specification: import_decl* definition+ eof` and the eof rule is `eof: EOF;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I just added newline characters to the `TOP_LEVEL_FALSE` and `TOP_LEVEL_TRUE`lexer rules an I also added the `top_level` parser rule to the definition rule because I only expected top_level to appear after a struct or union. this is a rti.com specific extension to the IDL-format, this modification seems to be good enough for me.

```
definition
  : type_decl SEMICOLON top_level?
  | const_decl SEMICOLON
  ...

TOP_LEVEL_TRUE
  : '//@top-level true' '\r'? '\n'
  ;

TOP_LEVEL_FALSE
  : '//@top-level false' '\r'? '\n'
  ;
```